# c++ and Linux go together - why are there no questions in this section?

Tags: discussion

C is the programming language Linux was originally written in.  I learned C many years ago, but haven't used it since college. (I'm an EE degree, computers were necessary, but programming was left primarily to the programmers).

Now, due to recent job requirements I am learning (and using) C++ specifically in the Linux environment - which isn't QUITE the same as using it in Windows.

Why are there no questions in the c++ section of unix stackexchange, and why, nearly immediately after asking a valid question, is my question almost immediately deleted?

I find it strange at best that the community wouldn't support questions concerning the very language that the OS evolved in.

Comment: I presume you mean this question http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/331432/c-and-linux-best-ide-programming-environment (note: deleted, so visible to 10k+ rep only)

Comment: It's just good moderation. And, there *are* questions tagged with `c++`. I see 146 of them - a sparse collection, to be sure. You wrote, "C is the programming language Linux was originally written in." Has Linus changed his mind to  embrace C++ and allow it into the kernel (http://harmful.cat-v.org/software/c++/linus)?  The OS did *not* "evolve" in C++.

Comment: Yes, your title is a bit confusing. C++ and Linux don't really go together at all. Or, rather, no more so than any other language. C and Linux yes, C++ not really since Linus seems to hate it with a passin.

Answer (score 21):

First, Unix & Linux is primary for *users* and *administrators* of Unix and Linux systems, not *programmers* of them. Programming questions, which almost all C++ questions would be, belong on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Second, we deal in questions which have reasonably objective correct answers. Through experience, we've learned that the Stack Exchange software & community just doesn't work well with questions that are mainly opinion-based, like "what's your favorite editor". Which is basically what you asked, and is why your question was closed & deleted.

If you are looking for an IDE with a *specific list of features*, then that is an answerable question if it were asked on our [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) site. Please refer to the help center there, in particular https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic, before asking.

Comment: To answer your response:
Many users and administrators of Unix and Linix systems are programmers, and I've seen many programming related questions on Stack Overflow.  (what does this command do?, how do I xxxx with a script? etc)

Second - That is exactly what I was looking for.  A list of features.  Not all features are "useful" and only those who have had extensive hands on experience with them would know the best features. 

I get that some people can opine about "I think this or that is better", but only those with hands on experience can actually tell what features work best.

Comment: Why would there be a /c++ section in stackexchange, if C++ related questions would be migrated to /discussion, or deleted altogether?

Why not just remove the /c++ section altogether rather than let people think they might get a valued answer to a valid question?

Comment: @bugstalker I'm not sure why you think scripting questions being allowed on Stack Overflow means you can ask programming questions here, those are unrelated things. We mention programming questions specifically in the ["What topis can I ask about here?"](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) section of our help. And I think you misunderstood the second point -- derobert means you would need to give a list of desired features and ask which IDE provides those features (and post it on softwarerecs). Questions that ask for the "best" anything are rarely useful because "best" is subjective

Answer (score 5):

This is basically a question of scope. Your [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/331432/22222) wouldn't be on topic anywhere on the Stack Exchange network. These are strictly Q&A sites and they all consider discussion off topic by definition. Specifically, your question was asking:

> Is there anyone out there commercially writing code in C++ using an IDE in Linux, that can recommend a particular one? Reasons why the one you use is better than others? etc. Intuitive and easy to learn is a bonus.
>
> I'm not asking for "I like this one better". That is subjective.
>
> What I need are specifics - how seamlessly the IDE you use works in Linux, what special capabilities and features it has that would make programming easier, less time consuming. I am looking for specific things that set the IDE you use apart from other similar IDE's.

While that last paragraph (which was added after the question was closed) makes an attempt at making it less of an opinion based question, you're still asking other people for their experience. If you were listing a set of specific features you would like your IDE to have, that might be on topic. As it is, you are asking people to tell you what they use why they like and what's so cool about it. This is a great discussion for chat or for any number of forums (or fora, if you prefer) out there. It's just not a valid question for a Stack Exchange site.

As for the community supporting the language the OS was coded in, none of the operating systems on topic here are written in C++. Or, rather, none of the main ones. I won't swear that there isn't any *nix system out there written in C++ but the most popular ones are all written in plain old C.

In any case, no matter what language the software was written in, programming is off topic here. The closest we get to programming questions is simple scripts to parse text, manipulate files and other sysadmin-type jobs. Questions about the workings of any language are off topic.

So, even if your question were actually valid for SE and had a single valid answer as opposed to being the seed of an interesting discussion, even then, questions about C would be off topic here. If you need help on installing the IDE of your choice, this is the place to ask. Not so for choosing one though.